# case insensitive matching search in string array swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In Swift 3, I want to create an array of matching string (case insensitive) from string array:-

I am using this code, but it is case sensitive,

```
let filteredArray = self.arrCountry.filter { $0.contains("india") }
```

how can I do this..
suppose I have a master string array called arrCountry, I want to create other array of all the string who has "india"(case insensitive) in it.

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can try with `localizedCaseInsensitiveContains`

```
let filteredArray = self.arrCountry.filter { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("india") }
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this method, always using range(of:...). Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

> **localizedCaseInsensitiveContains**
>   Returns a Boolean value indicating
>   whether the given string is non-empty and contained within this string
>   by case-insensitive, non-literal search, taking into account the
>   current locale. Locale-independent case-insensitive operation, and
>   other needs, can be achieved by calling
>   range(of:options:range:locale:).
>
> Equivalent to: range(of: other, options: .caseInsensitiveSearch,
>         locale: Locale.current) != nil

It's better to use

```
.filter { $0.range(of: "india", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

Comment: why is it better? your version seems more verbose; the other, more streamlined.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva because localized version uses the current Locale, but there can be cases, when the Locale is different then the language of the app.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way might be to lowercase your strings and compare:

**Swift 3 and above**

```
let filteredArray = self.arrCountry.filter { $0.lowercased() == "india" }
```

Answer (score 4):

### Answer 2020:

Even I put Chinese or Arabic, below test codes still returns TRUE

```
let text = "total sdfs"
let text1 = "Total 张"
let text2 = "TOTAL لطيف"
let text3 = "total :"
let text4 = "ToTaL : "



text.lowercased().contains("total")
text1.lowercased().contains("张")
text2.lowercased().contains("لطيف")
text3.lowercased().contains("total")
text4.lowercased().contains("total")


text.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("total")
text1.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("张")
text2.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("لطيف")
text3.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("total")
text4.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("total")
```

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents when using filtering (for example for lists in SwiftUI.
if You are filtering, empty string gives back false:

```
let filterString = ""
let s = "HELLO"
let f = s.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(filterString)
print(f)
```

so for example:

....

```
    private let people = ["Finn", "Leia", "Luke", "Rey"]


   func getList(filterString: String)->[String]{
        
        if filterString.isEmpty{
            return people
        }
        
        let result = people.filter({ (p: String) -> Bool in
            
            print(p)
            let f = p.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(filterString)
            return f
        })
        
        return result
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
let someArray = theRecentSavedData.filter({$0.labelToDisplay?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchBar.text ?? "") ?? false})
```

in someArray you will get all the string which matches

For example, if inside theRecentSavedData array you have a string like this **"Gel"**, and if you type **"gel"** it will give you Gel.